# What is the mechanism of the maven plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven

For example, does maven compiler plugin simply start a process to execute javac command when executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the maven compiler plugins it's exactly as you described, but other plugin's work differently. May the answer could be more specific if you questions would be more specific.